# Angular 4 compatibility issue with Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am Working with Angular 4, I am trying to use Bootstrap 4 in my application.
but getting the following error in command prompt while running the **npm start**

> Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be
>   determined. The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
>   Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli
>   and typescript in devDependencies, then delete node_modules and
>   package-lock.json (if you have one) and run npm install again.

Package.json file is as below

```
{
  "name": "cli-test4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.47",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-grid": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap-reboot": "^0.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "ng2-tooltip": "0.0.7",
    "ngx-quill": "^1.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.65",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

please provide a solution, or provide me a sample project on github with Angular 4, bootstrap 4

Comment: have you tried deleting the node_modules and doing the install again as the error states?

Comment: yeah, but no result getting same error

Comment: what is your node and angular version?  `node -v; ng version`

Comment: ng version::    Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 6.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 5.2.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.2.2
webpack: 3.11.0

Comment: hm.
what happens if you type `ng serve` ?

Comment: getting the following error in command prompt  ==>                                           Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if [this answer helps you:](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47592987/revisions)
Basically, create a fresh new angular project with `ng new my-app`, and check if that runs. If it does, copy all non-project related dependecies from the new app's package.json to your current project's, and try again.

Another solution is to try to install dev dependencies directly this: `npm install --dev`

If that won't help, then consider upgrading to Angular 5 maybe.

Comment: is there any effective changes in Angular 5 compare with Angular 4.

Comment: [here you can find](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced) the answer, but to summarize it : build optimizer developments, angular decorator support, some new pipes, zone speed improvements, new http client, routing improvements, etc.